Can't find a filter of a program in Procmon
I was given a task to put 2 filters in Procmon. 1) Process name is "test.exe" (a WinAPI createFile, readFile, closeHandle project written in Visual Studio in C) 2)Operation is read file. When I look for the filters I can't find either. I thought maybe I need to run the project for it to show, but even then, it doesn't. Do I need to do something extra? The file the project is reading is a simple text file with "Hello World!" written in it.
I have a photo of what the filters are supposed to look like (the "barakgonen.exe" is the "test.exe"): 
If it helps the code that reads the file is
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Specify the relative path to the file
    LPCSTR fileName = "C:\\TestFolder\\test.txt";

    // Attempt to open the file
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFileA(
        fileName,                // File name
        GENERIC_READ,            // Desired access
        0,                       // Share mode
        NULL,                    // Security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,           // Creation disposition
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,   // Flags and attributes
        NULL                     // Template file handle
    );

    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Could not open file (error %d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Buffer to store the data read
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD bytesRead;

    // Read data from the file
    BOOL readResult = ReadFile(
        fileHandle,              // File handle
        buffer,                  // Buffer to store data
        sizeof(buffer) - 1,      // Number of bytes to read
        &bytesRead,              // Number of bytes read
        NULL                     // Overlapped
    );

    if (!readResult) {
        printf("Could not read from file (error %d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        return 1;
    }

    // Null-terminate the buffer to make it a valid string
    buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';

    // Print the contents of the buffer
    printf("File contents:\n%s\n", buffer);

    // Close the file handle
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);

    return 0;
}


You say that the task is to put two filters in procmon. This program doesn't put any filters in procmon.

@Raymond Chen the code is what reads the file. Should I remove it from the question?

Oh, this is the program that you are trying to write a filter for. That's fine. But you never showed your filter.

@RaymondChen I have a photo of what it's supposed to look like. The task says I need to press Ctrl + L in Procmon and then check the filters I stated in the question.

Oh, I thought you were trying to create filters programmatically. This is less of a computer programming question now. (Note also that there's a scroll bar. Maybe there's another rule that is excluding your program when it runs.) Not sure what "(the "barakgonen.exe" is the "test.exe")" means. The filter must match the program name. A program has just one name.

@RaymondChen (the "barakgonen.exe" is the "test.exe") I meant that in the example, the program is called "barakgonen.exe". Thanks for the help. I'll try some other things

Since your program is not called "barakgonen.exe", that filter will not detect your program.

I don't understand the problem. Run Procmon, click on the filter button in the toolbar, add whatever they say. Done. You even have a screenshot. How can you miss it?

@ThomasWeller The problem is that I can't find find what I'm supposed to add to the filter. The photo is an example of how it's supposed to look

Step 1: click the filter button

Step 2. click the "Reset" button to make sure you have the default filters.

Step 3: Choose "Process name" from the drop down list

Step 4: Choose "is" from the drop down list

Step 5: Enter the name of the executable

Step 6: Choose "Include" from the drop down list

Step 7: Click "Add"

Result:

Step 8 to 12: Do it similarly for the other filter, starting from Step 3.
Step 13: Click "Ok" to apply the filters


Do I need to click "Apply" or just "Ok"?

@yarden. Just Ok is enough. Should be like that in most applications. Ok = Apply + Cancel/X.
